# SQL Server - Combine 5 queries into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have to create a report on the amount of Outbound Usages from Pharmacies
There are 4 types of outbound types: SMS, Call, Email, and P

I would like to get the total for each type and their sum for each pharmacy.

Here are my queries so far.

```
select PharmacyID, count(*) as total
from OutboundCallData
where datepart(year, DateReceived) = 2014 and datepart(month, datereceived) = 1
        and (NotificationMode = 'sms' or NotificationMode = 'call' or NotificationMode = 'email' or NotificationMode = 'p')
group by PharmacyID

select PharmacyID, count(*) as sms
from OutboundCallData
where datepart(year, DateReceived) = 2014 and datepart(month, datereceived) = 1
        and NotificationMode = 'sms'
group by PharmacyID

select PharmacyID, count(*) as call
from OutboundCallData
where datepart(year, DateReceived) = 2014 and datepart(month, datereceived) = 1
        and NotificationMode = 'call'
group by PharmacyID


select PharmacyID, count(*) as email
from OutboundCallData
where datepart(year, DateReceived) = 2014 and datepart(month, datereceived) = 1
        and NotificationMode = 'email'
group by PharmacyID


select PharmacyID, count(*) as p
from OutboundCallData
where datepart(year, DateReceived) = 2014 and datepart(month, datereceived) = 1
        and NotificationMode = 'p'
group by PharmacyID
```

I would like to combine all of these into one table that looks like this

```
PharmacyID| SMS | Call | Email | P | Total
-----------------------------------------
999000001 |  3  |  4   |   5   | 6 |  18
999000002 |  12 |  0   |   14  | 8 |  34
```

Displaying 0 or null would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cross tab will work for this:

```
select PharmacyID,
    count(*) as total,
    count(case when NotificationMode = 'sms' then 1 else null end) as sms,
    count(case when NotificationMode = 'email' then 1 else null end) as email,
    count(case when NotificationMode = 'call' then 1 else null end) as call,
    count(case when NotificationMode = 'p' then 1 else null end) as p
from OutboundCallData
where datepart(year, DateReceived) = 2014 and datepart(month, datereceived) = 1
        and (NotificationMode = 'sms' or NotificationMode = 'call' or NotificationMode = 'email' or NotificationMode = 'p')
group by PharmacyID
```

Alternately, you can use a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT PharmacyID, [sms], [email], [call], [p]
FROM
    (SELECT PharmacyID, NotificationMode 
        from OutboundCallData) AS outboundData
    PIVOT
    (
       count(NotificationMode )
       FOR NotificationMode IN ([sms], [email], [call], [p])
    ) AS P
```

Comment: This technique is referred to as a cross tab. I personally much prefer this to a PIVOT. I find them much easier to read and they have a slight edge on performance too. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the PIVOT keyword.

```
SELECT PharmacyID, [sms], [email], [call], [p]
FROM
    (SELECT PharmacyID, NotificationMode 
        from OutboundCallData
        where datepart(year, DateReceived) = 2014 and datepart(month, datereceived) = 1) o
    PIVOT
    (
       count(NotificationMode )
       FOR NotificationMode IN ([sms], [email], [call], [p])
    ) AS [PivotTable]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting an error saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

Comment: That was due to using `PIVOT` as a table name at the end.  I've remedied that now.